# React Typescript how to setState

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to learn typescript with react and I am pretty confused right now, how will I setState of an interface?
My code example:

```
interface Props {
    children: ReactNode | ReactNode[];
}

export interface IMovie {
    title: string;
    video: boolean;
    poster_path: string;
}
```

```
export const MoviesContext = createContext<IMovie[] | undefined>([]);

export const MoviesProvider = ({ children }: Props): JSX.Element => {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState<IMovie[]>();

    return (
            <MoviesContext.Provider value={[movies, setMovies]}>
                {children}
            </MoviesContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

The error I get is "Type (ΙΜovie[] | Dispatch> | undefined>> is not assignable to type IMovie[]"

any other suggestions on what to change on my code welcomed. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue here is the value type that your context is defined with is `IMovie`, where as the type being passed to your context during rendering is actually an array: `[movies, setMovies]`.

One solution would be to define and use a prop interface with your provider, that carries both the `movies` state as well as the setter for movies like this:

```
export interface IMovieProviderProps {
    movies? : IMovie,
    setMovies : (movies:IMovie) => void,
}
```

This `IMovieProviderProps` interface would then be used to define the shape of your context value, which would provide the means for accessing the `movies` state as well as updating it, from outside the provider:

```
/* Define context with new provider props */
export const MoviesContext = createContext<IMovieProviderProps>(null);

export const MoviesProvider = ({ children }: Props): JSX.Element => {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState<IMovie>();

    /* Define provider value. Can be done inline, but I've defined
    it here for clarity */
    const providerValue : IMovieProviderProps = {
        movies,
        setMovies
    }

    /* Pass providerValue to provider */
    return (<MoviesContext.Provider value={providerValue}>
        {children}
    </MoviesContext.Provider>);
};

/* Define a hook for this provider, that allows the provided value
to be consumed */
export const useMovies = () => useContext(MoviesContext);
```

The `useMovies` hook allows the provider value to be accessed from elsewhere in your project, and can be used like this:

```
const ExampleComponent = () => {

     /* Imported useMovies hook defined with provider above, and
     extract the movies state, and movies setter base on the shape
     of IMovieProviderProps */
     const { movies, setMovies } = useMovies();

     return <>
     {JSON.stringify(movies)}
     <button onClick={() => setMovies(null)}>Set Movies</button>
     </>
}
```

A key thing to note now is that the context now exposes an object value with the shape of `IMovieProviderProps` rather than an array value (as your code may have been expecting).

Hope that helps!

Comment: I try to use your example, at "const providerValue: IMovieProviderProps = {
        movies,
        setMovies
    }; " I get an error Type 'IMovie | undefined is not assignable to type IMovie

Comment: Sorry missed the `?` on provider props - does that help?

Comment: yeah that gives no errors but could you give me an example on how to use this in a component to setState
const providerValue = useContext<IMovieProviderProps | null>(MoviesContext);

Comment: Just extended answer - let me know if you need any more help :-)

Comment: thanks for this, but I have a couple of questions. First of all this " const [movies, setMovies] = useMovies() gives me an error " Property movies does not exist on type IMovieProviderProps | null" and I have to do something like this "const providerValues = useMovies();" and then providerValues?.movies.
Second question cause I am begginer and I am confused. I want movies to be an array of object so provider needs useState<IMovie[]> ?

Comment: You're welcome :-) There is a subtle difference here in that the value is not an array, and is instead a regular object, which means you should use the `{ .. }` rather than `[ .. ]` to extract `movies` and `setMovies` from the `useMovies()` result. Also yes, for `movies` to be a collection, you would define it as an array with `[]`. I can't fit more information here, but if you would like to open a new question and send me the link I can help you there :-)

Comment: Try this: `if(providerValues) {  const { movies, setMovies } = providerValues; /* use movies and setMovies here */ }`

Comment: hmm I dont know but that dont work, if i try to use setMovies or movies I get cannot find name 'movies' or 'setMovies'

Comment: Can you please post a new question for this particular issue and send me a link to that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60197157/react-typescript-destructure-providervalue