# React Typescript destructure providerValue

Tags: reactjs, typescript

After a suggestion of a member on my previous post on how to pass `setState` to children of context API, I have this code:

```
export interface IShowProviderProps {
    shows: IShow[];
    setShows: (currentShows: IShow[], shows: IShow[]) => void;
    sort: string;
    setSort: (sort: string) => void;
    query: string;
    setQuery: (sort: string) => void;
    showType: string;
    setShowType: (sort: "movie" | "tv") => void;
    page: number;
    setPage: (page: number) => void;
}

export const ShowContext = createContext<IShowProviderProps | null>(null);

export const ShowProvider = ({ children }: Props): JSX.Element => {
    const [shows, setShows] = useState<IShow[]>([]);
    const [sort, setSort] = useState<string>("popularity.desc");
    const [query, setQuery] = useState<string>("");
    const [showType, setShowType] = useState<"movie" | "tv">("movie");
    const [page, setPage] = useState<number>(1);

  const providerValue: IShowProviderProps = {
        shows,
        setShows,
        sort,
        setSort,
        query,
        setQuery,
        showType,
        setShowType,
        page,
        setPage
    };

 return <ShowContext.Provider value={providerValue}>{children}</ShowContext.Provider>;

export const useShows = () => useContext(ShowContext);
```

When I use context to children and I try something like this

```
 const {shows, setShows} = useShows();
```

I get error:

> Property 'shows' does not exist on type IShowProviderProps | null

And I have to do this:

```
 const providerValues = useShows();
```

and then 
`providerValues?.shows` (without ? I get possibly null)

what I have to do? thanks

Comment: `providerValues` is an object, not an array, so destructuring should be `const {shows, setShows} = useShows();`

Comment: yeah I did this with {}, wrong typing in my post, sorry, edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't work with TypeScript, so my answer might be not very accurate, but this line

```
const ShowContext = React.createContext<IShowProviderProps>({} as IShowProviderProps);
```

fixes the issue. The problem is that since `providerValues` *can* be `null`, TS compiler assumes that `null` must have `shows`, which it obviously doesn't.

There is nothing wrong with the logic. I assume `IShowProviderProps | null` was a workaround to keep TS compiler silent when you passed `null` as an initial value.

I dropped all your code in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-feather-88pgr), check this out -- it's all working.

BTW I believe `setShows: (currentShows: IShow[], shows: IShow[]) => void;` is a wrong signature for `setShows`. It takes the only argument which is either an `IShow` or `IShow => IShow`, but not two.

Comment: thanks for this, yeah I changed setShows already but thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that your Context's [value type is a union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) between `IShowProviderProps` and `null`:

```
/* The "IShowProviderProps | null" means that the value can be of type
   IShowProviderProps or type null */
export const ShowContext = createContext<IShowProviderProps | null>(null);
```

TypeScript will therefore consider the value of your Context as potentially being `null` and, will by default, report a compile error when you attempt to access fields on what is (potenntially) a `null` value:

```
/* Obtain context value - note that the value type is for this is
   IShowProviderProps | null, which means TypeScript sees showsValue
   as being potentially null */
const showsValue = useShows(); 

/* TypeScript won't allow access to shows, setShows, on a nullable value */
const {shows, setShows} = showsValue;
```

One solution here would be to simply define the value type of your Context as `IShowProviderProps`:

```
/* Removing "| null" causes TypeScript to now consider the value type of 
   ShowContext to be non-nullable, ie always defined */
export const ShowContext = createContext<IShowProviderProps>(null);
```

With that change, the need for any "null checking" of the context value at run-time can be discared as TypeScript will deduce that the Context value is always defined as type `IShowProviderProps`.

For these changes to work, you need to ensure that TypeScripts "strict mode" is disabled. That can be done by ensuring `"strict" : false` is present in the `compilerOptions` of your projects `tsconfig.js` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...

    "strict": false,

    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: the strict false works but I want to ask, is this a good practice to set it false? is it a better way to do it?
maybe user3272018's answer is better practice?

Comment: `strict : false` is not uncommon, however in most cases it would be preferable to have code base that is compliant with TypeScripts "strict" typing criteria