# How to push new input into Array with useStates (typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

This is all new to me and I'm still learning. I'm trying to create a form quiz, including an input title, an input question, and a few input answers (with a checkbox).

A button '+add answer' is created to be able to add new inputs 'answer' in the quiz.

I created an array of objects and now I need to be able to push into the array the new inputs when I click on the button '+add answer'. I know I have to use the .push() method, but the typescript makes it harder for me to know how to do that.

Here is the full code:

```js
function QuizForm() {

    const [inputTitle, setInputTitle] = useState<string>('');
    const [inputQuestion, setInputQuestion] = useState<string>('');
    const [answers, setAnswers] = useState<{
        correct: boolean,
        label: string,
        value: string,
        id: number
    }[]>([
        {
            correct: false,
            label: "Answer 1 ...",
            value: "",
            id: 0
        },

        {
            correct: false,
            label: "Answer 2 ...",
            value: "",
            id: 1
        }

    ]);



        return (
        <div className="container-fluid w-75">
            <h2 className="row my-3 justify-content-center title1">Quiz</h2>
            <div>

                <div className="row justify-content-center">
                    <Form.Control className="formbg form3" type="title" name="title"
                                  placeholder={'Quiz title ...'}
                                  onChange={(event => setInputTitle(event.target.value))}/>
                </div>

                <div className="row my-2 justify-content-center">
                    <Form.Control className="formbg form3" type="text" name="question" placeholder={'Question ...'}
                                  onChange={(event => setInputQuestion(event.target.value))}/>
                </div>

                {
                    answers.map((item) => {
                        return (
                            <>
                                <div className="row mt-4 justify-content-center">
                                    <Form.Control className="formbg form3" type="text" name="text" placeholder={item.label}/>
                                </div>

                                <div className="row">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="link1"/>
                                    <label htmlFor="link1" className="my-2">Good answer</label>
                                </div>
                            </>
                        )
                    })
                }




                <div className="my-4 line2"/>
            </div>

            <div className="row">
                <Button
                    className="addbutton border-0">+ add answer
                </Button>

            </div>
            <div className="row my-5 justify-content-center">
                <Button className="registerbutton" block size="lg" type="submit"
                        onClick={() => console.log({
                            inputTitle,
                            inputQuestion,
                        })}>Save</Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

}

export default QuizForm;
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: `<Button onClick={() => setAnswers([...answers, newAnswer])} className="addbutton border-0">+ add answer  </Button>` should do the job. Read more about useState hook and destructuring

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Typescript how to setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60130319/react-typescript-how-to-setstate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is that React state should be treated as immutable. So clicking the add answer button should invoke `setAnswers` passing in a *new* array of answers, which is constructed from the existing array, and appending the new answer.

```
<Button
  className="addbutton border-0"
  onClick={(ev) => {
    const id = answers.length;
    const newAnswer = {
       correct: false,
       label: `Answer ${id + 1} ...`,
       value: "",
       id,
    };
    setAnswers([...answers, newAnswer])
  }}
>+ add answer
</Button>
```

`Array.prototype.push()` is not suitable here because that mutates the existing array. `[...answers, newAnswers]` returns a *new* list which is a *copy* of the existing `answers`, along with `newAnswers` as the last element.

Comment: This worked!! Thank you so much for the help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually removing all my previous information as the answer can be found here.

[React Typescript how to setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60130319/react-typescript-how-to-setstate)

Comment: `setAnswers` is defined on Line 5. The OP's question seems to be how to invoke `setAnswers` to update the `answers`' state.

Comment: Sure sorry didnt see that was reading too quickly XD

Comment: I didn't know if I had to create a new function for that since I thought I could directly to that into my array

Comment: Not downvoting, but this should be a comment not an answer. Also, avoid pasting links unless you copy the important bits from there, because links may die over time

Comment: Sure will add the important bits. Thanks for the tip